# JSF PrimeFaces widget question

Tags: jsf, primefaces

It looks like PrimeFaces is partially based on jQuery UI.  I need a widget like the "Choice 1, Choice 2, Choice 3" row of buttons shown on this jQuery UI page (in the top left under "buttons):

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Is there a way to get a widget like this in PrimeFaces?

I'm currently using PrimeFaces 2.2.

Thanks!
rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToggleButtons have arrived.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1597

Answer (score 2):

This component will probably in 3.0.M2, I remember an issue ticket as a feature request for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no Primefaces component that looks like this.

What about the [Primefaces toolbar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/toolbar.jsf)?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The requirement from my user is something like the button bar like the one at the top of Apple.com.  The PrimeFaces toolbar is not quite right.

Comment: @Robert: I check Apple.com. This look to me like this is just a list of p:commandButton put together. Depend on the theme, the commandButton may have round corner, but we can easily fix this by changing CSS corner radius. What you think, Robert. If the button does not have round corner, putting them right next to each other will definitely generated the same look like what u desire